# Windows 10 "This app can't run on your PC" message after login - can't identify source

Tags: windows-10

I'm using windows 10 64-bit. For a while now I've been getting the blue message "This app can't run on your PC - To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher" every time after logging in. But I can't identify which app that is. Looking at the task manager's "start-up" section didn't help: Only programs listed there are Microsoft OneDrive (which I've disabled), NVIDIA Backend and Windows host process, which all shouldn't be the source of the problem.

Where/how can I identify the source of the error message?

Edit: Added screenshot of ["blue message"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU1UT.jpg)

Comment: What is "the blue message"? A screenshot would be nice. The answer to your question is likely Microsoft's Process Explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Comment: @Peter My bad, it's the same message as mentioned. Included a screenshot now.

Comment: A blocking Window without any relevant information? And Microsoft wonders why people hate them... The internet says this is sometimes caused by "SmartScreen", which should be turned off.

Comment: The error message keeps appearing with SmartScreen turned off. Currently figuring out how to handle the Process Explorer, will report with results.

Comment: Since it's a blocking window and the blue window seems to be popped up by Windows itself, I guess process explorer can't help either, sorry.

Comment: I'm hoping to identify it by the fact that it always appears after a login. (And might even remove some crapware while I'm on it)